# Create a binary matrix under certain conditions

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to create a function that given `m` and `p` returns a matrix with `m` rows and `mxp` columns. The matrix should have `0`'s except for `p` positions, starting at `p` (number of row).

For example, given `m=4` and `p=2`, the matrix should look like:

```
1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
```

I want to work with big matrices.
I know how to do this with loops in other programming languages such as python, but I am sure that it should be an easier and more elegant way to do this in R. I have been playing for a while with `diag()` without finding the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apply()`ing the `rep()` function to each row (or column, it's the same) of the diagonal matrix:

```
t(apply(diag(m), 2, rep, each = p))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
```

Answer (score 5):

This solution for `p=2` uses the change of the number of rows:

```
m <- 4
d <- diag(m)
matrix(rbind(d,d), m)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
```

For other values of `p` (from the comment of  A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1):

```
p <- 3; m <- 4
matrix(rep(diag(m), each = p), nrow = m, byrow = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
f <- function(m, p){
     a <- diag(m)
     a[,rep(seq_len(m), each=p)]
}

> f(m = 4, p = 2)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1

> f(m = 3, p = 4)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
#[2,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    0     0     0     0
#[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     1     1     1
```

The idea is to first create a diagonal matrix of size `m` (which we name `a`) and then repeat each column of that matrix `p` times (so `m*p` matrix).

Answer (score 4):

This method uses matrix subsetting to fill in the 1s.

```
myMatFunc <- function(m, p) {
  # initialize matrix of correct size, filled with 0s
  myMat <- matrix(0L, m, m * p)
  #fill in 1s using matrix subsetting
  myMat[cbind(rep(seq_len(m), each=p), seq_len(m * p))] <- 1L

  myMat
}
```

then,

```
myMatFunc(4, 2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
```

Thanks to the comments from @joseph-wood, @jogo, and @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 below, I improved the efficiency removing a call to `nrow` and a call to `ncol`, cut the size of the matrix in half by converting to integers, and fixed an initial testing typo.

Comment: Nice answers... however I think it should be `myMat <- matrix(0, m, m*p)`

Comment: Thanks for catching that typo.

Comment: shorter code: `myMat[cbind(rep(1:m, each=p), 1:(m*p))] <- 1` (but eventually not faster)

Comment: @jogo, longer code, but the fastest out of the options here: `myfun <- function(m, p) {M <- matrix(0L, ncol = m*p, nrow = m); C <- seq.int(m*p); R <- rep(seq.int(m), each = p);M[cbind(R, C)] <- 1L;M}`. Though I would be surprised if efficiency is really a concern for a function like this....

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R solution that is pretty fast:

```
Joseph <- function(m, p) {
  mat <- matrix(0L, nrow = m, ncol = m*p)
  for (i in 1:m) {mat[i, p*(i-1L) + 1:p] <- 1L}
  mat
}
```

Here are some equality comparisons:

```
fun989 <- function(m, p){
  a <- diag(m)
  a[,rep(seq_len(m), each=p)]
}

IMO <- function(m, p) {
  myMat <- matrix(0L, m, m*p)
  myMat[cbind(rep(seq_len(nrow(myMat)), each=p), seq_len(ncol(myMat)))] <- 1
  myMat
}

JOGO <- function(m, p) {matrix(rep(diag(m), each = p), nrow = m, byrow = TRUE)}
APOM <- function(m, p) {t(apply(diag(m), 2, rep, each = p))}

library(compiler)
enableJIT(3)  ## compiling each function
all.equal(Joseph(100, 50), fun989(100, 50))
[1] TRUE
all.equal(Joseph(100, 50), APOM(100, 50))
[1] TRUE
all.equal(Joseph(100, 50), JOGO(100, 50))
[1] TRUE
all.equal(Joseph(100, 50), IMO(100, 50))
[1] TRUE
enableJIT(0)  ## return to standard setting
```

Here are the benchmarks:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(Joseph(100, 50), JOGO(100, 50), fun989(100, 50), APOM(100, 50), IMO(100, 50), unit = "relative")
Unit: relative
           expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval cld
Joseph(100, 50)  1.000000  1.000000 1.000000  1.000000  1.000000 1.000000   100  a 
  JOGO(100, 50) 33.388929 20.892988 6.593804 22.365625 19.161056 1.167957   100   b
fun989(100, 50)  7.192071  4.577225 2.044973  4.432824  4.129563 1.029050   100  a 
  APOM(100, 50) 40.244128 28.176729 8.805715 27.785985 23.966477 1.209582   100   b
   IMO(100, 50)  6.119685  3.898451 2.712222  6.192030  6.033916 1.044422   100  a
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it but I would choose @989 answer over mine;

```
 cadv.func = function(m,p)
{

  cmat <- matrix(data=NA,nrow=m,ncol=m*p)
  cmat[is.na(cmat)] <- 0

  for (i in 1:m){
    for (j in 1:p){

    cmat[i,j+p*(i-1)] = 1

  } 
  }

  return(cmat)
}

cadv.func(4,2)


 #       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
 # [1,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
 # [2,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0
 # [3,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
 # [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
```

Comment: This doesn't return the correct results. I think the problem lies with `cmat[i,j + 2*(i-j)] = 1`

Comment: It should be `cmat[i,j + p*(i-j)] = 1`

Comment: @JosephWood Thanks for your comment. I made a mistake. 2 works only for `p=2`.  But `(i-1)` should still remain the same.